# Batch large JSON data set in JavaScript and post it to server

Tags: javascript, json, es6-promise

It may be a silly question, but couldn't find the proper code sample with best approach in JavaScript. I have 1000's JSON of object and want to send 100 by 100. After getting success as response i want to send next 100. Thanks in advance

Comment: _“but couldn't find the proper code sample”_ - well, we are not here to go and _search_ stuff for you. And as a Senior Developer, according to your profile I’d rather expect you to do a bit better of a job at explaining to us what the actual problem is. Please go read [ask].

Comment: @misorude : I haven't asked you to search code for me in first place. Have asked for the best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually is quite simple if you're considering using `async/await`. The concept is to send your json `Synchronously`.

1. Split your payload
2. Synchronously await until your server gave it response
3. Handle the response (proceed reject if error occurs, this will break the loop)
4. Proceed change the index

Haven't test the code but, more or less it should be like this.

```
const x = [{...}] // assuming that x is your array of object

const sendByChunks = async (chunkSize) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let start = 0
    let end = 0

    while (start <= x.length) {
      try {
        end = (end + chunkSize) > x.length ? x.length : (end + chunkSize) // set the end index
        const payload = x.slice(start, end) // slice the array
        start = end
        await postBatchData(payload) // send to your API
      } catch (error) {
        reject(`Error postBatchData from ${start} to ${end}`) // log something
      }
      resolve('Success')
    }
  })
}
sendByChunks(100)
  .then(response => { // handle response (your resolve) })
  .catch(error => { // handle error (your reject) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the while loop it should be < instead of <=. Otherwise it will run into infinite loop

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33564587)